# Value of Joker options

Tags: yomi

**How should one compare the value between the two main options of Jokers?**

In Yomi, Jokers have two primary purposes: *Gold Burst*, which allows one to gain aces, and *Time Rewind* (also affectionately known as *Blue Burst*), which acts as a "combo breaker" when being hit.  There are also other minor uses, such as using them for pumping fodder in extreme cases.

Being so rare and having powerful effects, Joker's are extremely valuable.  As such, it becomes important to judge the opportunity cost of the two options against each other.  It seems to be a general guideline that Blue Burst is substantially more valuable than Gold Burst in the broadest strokes, but it is not a hard rule.

What is the estimated mathematical value between the two options?  In what situations or character match-ups does it significantly change?  If one is playing for winning in the long-term over multiple games, as one might do in Poker, what is the most conservative way to value these cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to math this out.  It also depends on the game situation.  For example, if you are behind by 30 HP and on the brink of death, that blue burst might save you from a dodge into attack followup, but it probably won't save you from anything else.  Even then, you might have a hard time winning after using it.  A gold burst can get you the two aces you need to have the damage in hand necessary to kill your opponent.

In general, characters like Argagarg and Rook cannot add a large amount of damage to their combos, so gold bursting against them is better.  Characters that have high combo potential like Valerie and Zane generally give you more opportunity to prevent damage with a blue burst.  Gold burst can only be done when you read the opponent to attack or throw so it can win combat, and should only be done when taking the risk to get aces is one of your only options.

Comment: I disagree that it should "only be done when taking the risk to get aces is one of your only options". It should be done when you want the aces more than the ability to undo damage, and when you think you have a better chance of landing it (either by reading the opponent's play, knowledge about their hand, or by knocking them down).

Answer (score 1):

Blue burst is more valuable for simple reason. Let's compare them

**Blue burst:**
+ It's more certain to hit than gold burst
+ It gives +1 card advantage
+ It makes you immune to damage
- OR -
+ It gives you card advantage over opponent that thinks you are bluffing

**Gold burst:**
+ It's less certain to hit than blue burst generally 50% case.
+ It can give opponent chance to retaliate for free
+ It gives +1 card advantage, while it gives +2/3 card advantage compared to power-up (3 cards for 2 aces)
- Other cards can achieve similar effect, and can recur more often.
- If you lose your opponent is almost guaranteed to gets some free damage in.

With blue burst, you win whether opponent does something or not (assuming you played a Joker). With gold burst it's a bit more all-in.

Comment: While each option gives the same numerical card advantage gain, it certainly seems worthy of note that the 2 deterministic cards drawn from Gold Burst have a much higher chance of being much more valuable than the 2 random cards from Blue Burst.

Comment: That's the problem. The draw from blue burst is more reliable than from gold burst.

Comment: You misunderstand.  I am saying that, while you have a higher chance of getting the cards with Blue Burst, you have a higher chance of getting GOOD cards with Gold Burst (since Aces are usually near the top, albeit not usually the very best, cards you can get in the typical scenario).  In that sense, Gold Burst is more "reliable" in terms of getting consistent value.